# why 32bit of memory requires only 1 bit of the map

Tags: c, memory-management, bitmap, operating-system

I am reading the book modern operating system from Tannenbaum on `Memory Management with Bitmaps` but finding it hard to understand what he meant by this statement

> The smaller the al- location unit, the larger the bitmap. However,
>   even with an allocation unit as small as 4 bytes, 32 bits of memory
>   will require only 1 bit of the map.

Why will 4 bytes (32bit) of memory occupy only 1 bit in the map?

[image: screenshot from book]

Comment: if the bit is 1 then the unit of memory allocated, if 0 then it's free, unit being 4 bytes here. it's clearly written. what's the question?

Comment: @user3528438 my question is is the memory allocation 4byte to 1 bit in bitmap. i am confuse there. Or the 1 bit just says a memory is allocated

Comment: The question is the word "only": 1 bit per 4 bytes for 4 GB is still an awfull lot of memory for the map. I would write "_However ... will require still..._"

Comment: When [editing posts](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45134629/revisions), please make as many appropriate changes as are needed on the post. Something that might help is the [Magic™ Editor user script](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/Magic%E2%84%A2Editor.user.js), which can make many common changes. However, it's **not** perfect. I often need to revert what it does in the edit window. Some of its change-rules are over aggressive. You **need** to review each portion of the changes for appropriateness, but it does help.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for  the hint. something is confusing what is right here. Take a look at what i did and community rejected it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16723597)

Comment: The community user is the account that's used for automated actions. As stated in the reject reason: "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit", what happened was that someone else made an edit after yours without explicitly reviewing your edit. This could be intentional. It could also be that they were not notified of your edit prior to submitting theirs, or that they had completed their edit, but not submitted, prior to being notified. If it was intentional, I would expect that person to have rejected and edited, but that's not the case. Given everything, it was most likely unintentional.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for deep explanation. i got to learn a lot here. Thanks

Comment: It's also possible to end up in a situation where someone with edit privileges (>2k rep) forces an edit, which looks the same as on that edit. While I've done so on a some occasions, it's something that's rare (and more convoluted form a UI point of view). I've done so when I'm unable to approve/reject & edit (because I'd already reviewed) & the question is near to being closed. The first edit after a question is closed automatically places the question in the reopen review queue to be evaluated for reopening. In general, that's a bad thing if the edit doesn't make the (continued)

Comment: question on-topic, which is very rare for anyone other than the OP to be able to do. Thus, prior to voting to close a question, I'll ensure that any pending edits are rejected or applied in order to prevent the edit from being applied shortly after the question is closed. The take away from the above is: don't edit closed questions as the first edit after they've been closed, unless your edit can make the question on topic, which is very rare. Note: that's not what your did, it's just where my rambling talk ended up, but the Q you asked about was close to closure when the other user edited.

Comment: @Makyen yea i will take that in mind. I edited it in the middle of the night. I waited for more than 30 minutes but wan't approved yet so i went to sleep. I think it was marked as duplicate afterwards. I am not hearing of this privilege edit. Thanks man.

Comment: There are a [bunch of privleges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) which you earn as you get more reputation (rep). Being able to [edit questions and answers without having to go through the suggested edit review queue is at 2k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). The other one I mentioned, [voting to close/reopen questions is at 3k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @Makyen hahahha have not checked those stuffs. Thanks more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bitmap in this context is being used to indicate what blocks of memory are being allocated.

> Why will 4 bytes (32bit) of memory occupy only 1 bit in the map?

They don't OCCUPY 1 bit. One bite determines if the 4 bytes are in use.

> The smaller the allocation unit, the larger the bitmap. However, even with an allocation unit as small as 4 bytes, 32 bits of memory will require only 1 bit of the map.

Assume you have a memory pool of 1024 bytes and are going to use this technique. If you allow allocation of 128 bytes, that means you only need 8 bits for your bitmap (8*128 = 1024). If you allocations of 64 bytes, you need 16 bites for your bitmap.

I have to say that this is a normal and customary means of indicating allocated disk clusters, I doubt it is used much for memory.

Answer (score 0):

The text you tagged as red background color may contain some mistakes. If every 32 bits of memory uses 1 bit to identify if it's allocated, the bitmap will take **1/33** of the memory.
After all, in my book edition, this number appears to be 1/33.